# Is is possible to get the authentication endpoint for external services (Facebook, Google, etc) from OWIN using oAuth2?

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth, owin, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to find out how to get the external provider login endpoint from OWIN. I'm using the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google (using v3.0.1) api. I've debugged the startup.auth.cs and debugged the override to the ExecuteResult() procedure of the .ChallengeResult() method is sent off but I cannot seem to find out how to get the endpoint out of the OWINContext. Any ideas?

Account Controller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;

internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
    : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
{
}

public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
{
    LoginProvider = provider;
    RedirectUri = redirectUri;
    UserId = userId;
}

public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }

public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
    if (UserId != null)
    {
        properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
    }

    Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext _context = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
    AuthenticationTicket _at = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie), properties);


    temp(_context, _at);

    context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
}
```

startup.auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;

public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        var google = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = GoogleClientId,
            ClientSecret = GoogleClientSecret,
        };

        //google.Scope.Add("email");
        google.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(google);

        app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. For anyone that may come across this issue here's how you get the endpoint

in the file Startup.Auth.cs, which can be found in the APP_START folder. you need to add the ability to set a breakpoint in the OWIN middleware. 
I set the code for the breakpoint after app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

here is the actual code for Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

the app.use allows you to set breakpoints in the middleware. this will allow you to check the "context". After you select an external login provider. I used Google as an example. the context.response.statuscode changes from a 401 to a 302. Check the context.response.headers and you'll see LOCATION added to the headers. Here is where you'll be able to get the authorization endpoint with all  the querystring parameters included. In my case i can now use this URL to programmatically login to google and/or give consent.